# Resize x-axis with saving the information

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to resize my x-axis depends on variable `nr_of_sec` with saving the information.

Example: I have a plot with 125 poins at x-axis for 1 sec - well; 
and then I get 250 values at x-axis for 2 sec - it means I need to make my x-axis twice less[0,125] without losing information -> in this way i should have twice points more at x-axis than with example for 1 sec.

I have some kind of signal(for 1 sec 250 timesteps).

I get a frequency(Fast Fourier Transform) plot that for 1 sec has 125 points in frequency axis(i cut a symmetric part, that's why not 250 points).

The following code is:

```
nr_of_sec = 1  
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
pointdat=tracesM[378,28*250:(28+nr_of_sec)*250]
this = np.fft.fft(pointdat-np.mean(pointdat))
thisi = int(len(this)/2)
thisii = this[:(thisi)]
thisii = np.abs(this[:(thisi)])
plt.plot(thisii)
plt.grid(color='black')
plt.title('1 sec for point 378')
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('power')
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=20)
locY = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locY)
plt.show()
```

And i've got the plot:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKrNY.png)
Values are equal:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNJzU.png)

And for 2 sec I have the same code (the only change is `nr_of_sec` that is equal 2).

I get the following plot:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm2VY.png)
Values are equal:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS7vJ.png)

I tried to find information about how to solve this kind of problem but it was unsuccessful. 
Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what `tracesM` is. I have the impression you should play around explicitly with the resolution and the length scale

1. when setting up the problem
2. using the same parameters for the graphics again

Below a toy example to illustrate what I mean.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

NT1, NT2 = 125,   250                           # number of points for the resolution
L1,  L2 =  np.pi, 2*np.pi                       # length scale of the function

t1 = np.linspace(0,L1,NT1)                       # time axis 1
t2 = np.linspace(0,L2,NT2)                       # time axis 2

f1 = np.sin(t1) + 0.1* np.random.randn(len(t1))  # function 1
f2 = np.sin(t2) + 0.1* np.random.randn(len(t2))  # function 2

with plt.style.context('fivethirtyeight'):    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,7)) 
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.plot(t1,f1)
    ax.plot(t2,f2-0.2)
    plt.savefig('graphics.png');plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: 1) 'tracesM' is my matrix of int data where rows are particular points(i've chosen 378 point in my example above) and columns are timesteps(one minute is equal 250 timesteps); 2)  it's not exactly what i want; (using your example) how to make your red function twice 'compacted' without losing information and without changing the formula of your 'f2' (i need to make changes in plot); example: i want the point 6 that has the value '-0.5' now would be a point 3(x-axis) and would leave the same value '-0.5'. @pyano

Comment: to achiev that you can vary either NT, L or t. To see it on the plot, your plot command **must have** both: x-values and y-values (`ax.plot(t1,f1)`). The plot command given in your  code includes y-values only (`plt.plot(thisii)`)